# 変数の中に、文字列がある場合には、欠損値とする方法

Tags: python

文字列がある場合には、欠損値np.nanにしたいと考えています。
現在は、次のようなコードを考えています。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [3, 'TV', np.nan]})

#文字列がある場合には、欠損値とする。
df['x'].applymap(lambda row: np.nan if type(row) is str, axis=1)
```

しかし、エラーが出ます。

```
df['x'].applymap(lambda row: np.nan if type(row) is str, axis=1)
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

xを次のようにしたいのですが、

```
{'x': [3, np.nan, np.nan]}
```

どなたか、ご教示頂けるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df['x']`は、`Series`なので`axis`がないためエラーになっています。`apply`を使うのであれば、以下のようにします。

```
df['x'] = df['x'].apply(lambda row: np.nan if type(row) is str else row)
```

しかし、`to_numeric`を使う方が簡単で高速に処理できます。

```
df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: うまくいきました。to_numericをご教示くださいまして、ありがとうございます。